# Place numbering in systeme package to the left

Tags: systeme

How can I put the numbering in the  systeme package to the left instead to the right?

The "naive" approach as in the following example doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\sysdelim..

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}

% This doesn't work:
% \systeme{
% \mathrm{I} @ 2x + 3y = 4,
% \mathrm{II} @ -x + 7y = -1
% }

\end{document}
```

Comment: anyway, the command suffixed `@iii` in the systeme package can most likely be altered to swap the numbering.

Comment: Sorry, I had a trailing systeme.tex document in the same folder. I'll check it out tomorrow somewhere... This shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @1010011010 Did you succed in making it work?

Comment: equations in system can be numbered automatically

Comment: For automatically numbered equations Roman number  try  `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral*}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a workaround, we can change the position of numbering with `\syscodeextracol`
the default is `\syscodeextracol{\kern1.5em$}{$}` which mean `1.5em` from the end of equation, the two `$` to put numbering inside math mode.
Depending on the length of the equation we can change the position of numbering with negative space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}


\begin{document}

\sysdelim..

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}

\bigskip
\syscodeextracol{\kern-8.5em\hfill$}{$\kern8.5em}

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}

\bigskip
\syscodeextracol{\kern1.5em$}{$}% return to default

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update 1**

To simplify the code we can create two commands `\rightnum{width of equation}` and `\leftnum` to switch between numbering on the right or on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\newcommand{\rightnum}[1]{\syscodeextracol{\kern-#1\hfill$}{$\kern#1}}
\newcommand{\leftnum}{\syscodeextracol{\kern1.5em$}{$}}% return to default

\begin{document}

\sysdelim..

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}

\bigskip
\rightnum{8.5em}

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}

\bigskip
\leftnum

\systeme{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II} 
}


\end{document}
```

**Update 2**

You can  define the  width of the box containing the whole system of equations as the length of negative space,
in this case you do not need to enter manually any space to left align numbering.

Here to put numbering on left side we use `\systemeL` command, for numbering on the right we keep on command `\systeme`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\newlength{\systemewd}

\newcommand\systemeL[2][]{
\settowidth{\systemewd}{\systeme{#2}}
\syscodeextracol{\kern-\systemewd\hfill$}{$\kern\systemewd}
\systeme [#1]{#2}
\syscodeextracol{\kern1.5em$}{$}}


\begin{document}

\sysdelim..

\systemeL{
2x + 3y + 4z = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y - 6z = -1 @ \mathrm{II}, 
3x +  y - 2z = 3 @ \mathrm{III}
}

\bigskip

\systeme{
2x + 3y + 4z = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y - 6z = -1 @ \mathrm{II}, 
3x +  y - 2z = 3 @ \mathrm{III}
}

\bigskip

\systemeL[yx]{
2x + 3y = 4 @ \mathrm{I},
-x + 7y = -1 @ \mathrm{II}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But do I understand you correctly, that I have to adjust the \kern parameter for each system individually?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is the method here. 
 or if you have a way to know the length of the longest equation this could simplify matters

Comment: Thanks thats what I wanted. I just wondered how to make the numbers on  the left also left aligned, but this seems to be no problem because I can just change `\syscodeextracol{\kern-\systemewd\hfill$}{$\kern\systemewd}` to `\syscodeextracol{\kern-\systemewd$}{$\kern\systemewd}`